# Using C POSIX sockets, can you determine how many bytes a socket contains without extracting?

Tags: c, sockets, posix

I'm working with POSIX sockets in C.

**Given X, I have a need to verify that the `socketfd` contains at least X bytes before proceeding to perform an operation with it.**

With that being said, I don't want to receive X bytes and store it into a buffer using `recv` as X has the potential of being very large.

My first idea was to use `MSG_PEEK`...

```
int x = 9999999
char buffer[1];
int num_bytes = recv(socketfd, buffer, X, MSG_PEEK);
(value == X) ? good : bad;
...
...
...
// Do some operation
```

But I'm concerned X > 1 is corrupting memory, flag `MSG_TRUNC` seems to resolve the memory concern but removes X bytes from socketfd.

Comment: Speculation: the OS is unlikely to ever buffer "very large" amount of bytes. If it's too much for your process, it's probably too much for kernel too. Or you may have to do some OS-specific configuration to enable large enough kernel buffer.

Comment: What is your purpose here, anyway?

Comment: Simulating an HTTP/1.1 server. Attempting to wait for client to receive X bytes before I start removing data to perform an operation.

Comment: "I don't want to receive X bytes and store it into a buffer using recv as X has the potential of being very large." - So you would leave it in a kernel buffer? It is going to have to be buffered any way you look at it.

Comment: Yeah, TCP/IP doesn't have a side channel to tell how many bytes are waiting to be sent. It does have throttling, so data is not lost, and there is an implicit expectation that the application will read as much data as it can as soon as it can process it.

Comment: So short answer is "no".

Answer (score 1):

There's a big difference between e.g. TCP and UDP in this regards.

UDP is packet based, you send and receive packets of fixed size, basically.

TCP is a *streaming* protocol, where data begins to stream on connection and stops at disconnection. There are no message boundaries or delimiters in TCP, other than what you add at the application layer. It's simply a stream of bytes without any meaning (in TCP's point of view).

That means there's no way to tell how much will be received with a single `recv` call.

You need to come up with an application-level protocol (on top of TCP) which can either tell the size of the data to be received; For example there might be a fixed-size data-header that contains the size of the following data; Or you could have a specific delimiter between messages, something that can't occur in the stream of bytes.

Then you receive in a loop until you either have received all the data, or until you have received the delimiter. But note, with a delimiter there's the possibility that you also receive the beginning of the *next* message, so you need to be able to handle partial beginnings of message after the current message have been fully received.

Comment: I'm actually doing this as an HTTP/1.1 exercise. 

X is my content-length header. I want to block until at least X bytes are received without the overhead of storing it into an X sized buffer.  I'm getting the feeling this isn't feasible.

Comment: If `X` is "insanely big", your read will never succeed because the kernel won't buffer an insane amount of data. Instead, it will stop acknowledging data received, which will cause the sender to send more slowly (or not at all). That's part of TCP's adaptation algorithm, which is extremely useful. Just read the data and stash it in a temporary file if you think that's necessary.

Comment: Also, note that content-length is the length of the content, not the length of the transmission. If the transmission is compressed, they won't correspond, and you'll again probably never manage to complete the read.

Comment: Above comments for @jason.

Answer (score 0):

```
int num_bytes = recv(socketfd, buffer, X, MSG_PEEK);
```

This will copy up to X byte into buffer and return it without removing it from the socket. But your buffer is only 1 byte large. Increase your buffer.

Have you tried this?

```
ssize_t available = recv(socketfd, NULL, 0, MSG_PEEK | MSG_TRUNC);
```

Or this?

```
size_t available;
ioctl(socketfd, FIONREAD, &available);
```

Comment: I want the return, number of bytes read, so that I can assert there is at least X bytes without extracting the data or making an insanely large buffer.
 
Perhaps I set both flags? `MSG_TRUNC | MSG PEEK`

Comment: From what I can observe both methods gave me the desired results and Valgrind indicated no issues as well.